# Evaluating Regular Expressions at compile time in D

Tags: regex, d, compile-time, ctfe

Is there a way to evaluate regular expressions in D, at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `static` variable of type `std.regex.ctRegex`.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_regex.html#ctRegex

Comment: I already tried that, but the returned Captures aren't available at compile time, and casting them immutable will not allow me to get the result.

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Evaluating if a string matches a regex and fetch the match.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, the straightforward CTFE of plain regex doesn't work since it uses malloc! Rewriting it is a bit of a pain for that to, blargh.

Comment: I took a shot at it but then you run into issues with casting pointers, which doesn't work with CTFE...

Comment: Yeah, and it does this throughout the file too. I think the best option here is to not use regex here...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Any alternatives?

Comment: The best option that comes to mind is to break down the regex into simpler string functions like indexOf etc.